# Relations counting

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am learning relations ansni found question i cannot answer. How many relations talhat are non symetric and also non antisimetric are there?

I tried to draw a matrix but cannotsee the right answer

How can i find out? Thanks

Comment: On a given finite set, you mean?

Comment: Yes on set with size n , for example 4 basicly n

Comment: What do the words "ansni" and "talhat " mean?

Comment: Well, the set of symmetric relations on a given finite set, and the set of anti-symmetric relations on that same finite set, are disjoint sets. So all you have to do is calculate the cardinality of the set of all relations on a given finite set, and then subtract the sum of the cardinality of the set of symmetric relations and the cardinality of the set of anti-symmetric relations. So there are three sets whose cardinality you have to compute. How about the first one, the cardinality of the set of all binary relations on a set of a given finite cardinality n? Do you know what that is?

Comment: @Rupert no, a relation can be both symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Comment: What's the definition of anti-symmetric then?

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a set $X$. A relation $R$ on $X$ is a subset $R \subseteq X \times X$. Now, assume we have a relation $R$ which we know is both symmetric and anti-symmetric and let $(x,y) \in R$ be an element in the relation.
Since $R$ is symmetric, we must have $(y,x) \in R$, and since $R$ is anti-symmetric, this implies that $x = y$. Hence *all* elements of $R$ must be of the form $(x,x)$.

Conclusion: The only symmetric and anti-symmetric relations on $X$ are the identity relations $\{(y,y) \mid y \in Y \subseteq X\} \subseteq X \times X$ (and also vacuously the empty relation).
For example, if $X$ has $1$ element $x_1$, then the only choices are $\emptyset$ and $\{(x_1, x_1)\}$, and if $X$ has $2$ elements $x_1, x_2$, then the choices are $\emptyset$, $\{(x_1,x_1)\}$, $\{(x_2,x_2\}$, and $\{(x_1,x_1),(x_2,x_2)\}$.

So if $X$ has $n$ elements, then the number of symmetric and anti-symmetric relations is...?